# Pure HTML export buttons in jQuery Data Table

Tags: html, button, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables. It provides set of export buttons. But those buttons are swf buttons.

I would like to have HTML drop down buttons. I have gone through its help but could not found such code to set HTML5 buttons other than built in Flash.

I would like to have drop down buttons like below

> Export
>        - PDF
>        - CSV
>        - HTML
>        - Excel

Above buttons are set of HTML tags (generally what they are in HTML). Can I do that?

### **Edit:**

I would like to generate buttons using `button`, `div`, `ul`, `li` tags combination which we generally do in our regular HTML files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### SOLUTION

Use the code below for HTML5 export buttons that don't use Flash.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      {
         extend: 'collection',
         text: 'Export',
         buttons: [ 'pdfHtml5', 'csvHtml5', 'copyHtml5', 'excelHtml5' ]
      }
   ]
});
```

You need to use [Download Builder](http://datatables.net/download/index) to include DataTables, Buttons, HTML5 export, JSZip and pdfmake libraries to produce links to CDN for JS/CSS files.

#### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gr5er1pj/1/) for code and demonstration.

#### LINKS

- [HTML5 export buttons](http://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html)
- [Button - collection](http://datatables.net/reference/button/collection)

Comment: Can't I set HTML code (div, buttons, a etc. tags) in buttons and apply HTML classes? Because these buttons do not feet to my requirements.

Comment: @NullPointer, These are pure HTML buttons. See [Button - Options](http://datatables.net/reference/option/#buttons), you can set class with [`buttons.buttons.className`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.buttons.className) option. You can also create [custom buttons](http://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/custom).

Comment: What if I want to add HTML tags? Because my static HTML design includes 'Export' as button tag, and sub menu is comprise of <div> and <ul> <li> under it. Sorry for more questions.

Comment: @NullPointer, you can use your own layout/design and trigger DataTables buttons programmatically via API [`button().trigger()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/button%28%29.trigger%28%29), see https://jsfiddle.net/gr5er1pj/2/

Comment: I just checked your jsfiddle, thank you very much for that, you have created two `a` tags for button but they are located separately. Can't I modify buttons generated through data tables? Or in other words can't I write pure html tags in buttons property in data tables?

Comment: I have edited my question for specific direction. So please have a look too.

Comment: How to understand `table.button( '0-0' ).trigger();` in your jsfiddle example?

Comment: @NullPointer, it's poorly documented yet, but I understand it as zero-based indexes, first `0` is zero-based index of button **Export** and second `0` is zero-based index of button in the collection which is **PDF**.

Comment: I am trying to bind click of Flash buttons with other html element. Is that possible?

Comment: I could not able to find that buttons using `0-0` :(

Comment: I am getting following error in my code "SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script table.button("

Comment: @Gyrocode.com do you have any idea how to enable the dialog box for html5button export.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com how to add a callback for export complete?? for the above button syntax

Comment: @Reddy, there is [`button-action`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/button-action) event that is triggered when a button is pressed, would that work for you?

Comment: @Gyrocode.com my scenario is once the export is  complete I need to manipulate the Table DOM like removing some rows, if at all I do it on button pressed event then the export is messing up. So I decided to do it once the export is complete... There is this `"fnComplete"` here https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/button_options but the property name must change in your syntax, I was wondering what that might be here.

Comment: @Reddy, you're referencing retired TableTools option. With the new Buttons extension, I don't see such ability available unfortunately.

Comment: I am getting `table.button is not a function`. Can you please tell exactly which files I should import from the `Download builder` package?

Comment: @HalfBloodPrince, the minimal set is mentioned in the answer: DataTables, Buttons, HTML5 export, JSZip and pdfmake. Also make sure you're using 'DataTable()` instead of 'dataTable()'.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com How do I set `filename` of pdf and excel files? And I also want to set header in pdf file.